# Using SQL Table in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-phone

I found two links for creating a SQL Database. What is the difference between two approaches? Which one is better? [This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671) or
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202876%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?
I need my app to run on all versions of windows phone(7,7.5,8)

thanks in advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your application to run on WP7, 7.5 and 8, then go with what the second link mentions - local database in your app.

Sqlite is officially supported in Windows Phone 8 only so that will not be the best choice for you.

Sqlite is more powerful, and cross platform with other mobile ecosystems, but not with older version of Windows Phone.

Comment: Sqlite also support on wp7,7.X

Comment: AFAIK Sqlite is only supported on windows phone 8. If it supports Please provide the link where it support wp7,7.x . I am using linq2sql for making database,will it work fine for wp8,7,7.x or there is any limitations.I have to store around 200kb of data and database is to be updated frequently?